# Know the matrix A and matrix-vector product Ax, how to calculate possible vector x?

Tags: r, algorithm, vector, matrix

e.g. I know a product of one matrix and one vector being:

```
Ax=[
1
−3
].
```

and I know that said matrix A is

```
A=
[1 −1 2
 0 −3 1]
```

how can i calculate the possible vector(or the nx1 matrix) x?

=========

in addition to the basic question:

now that i know there are cases where no feasible solution can be found and cases where multiple answers are possible; in the latter case one solution would be sufficient however in the former case, is it possible to find a vector y where Ay would be as close to Ax as possible (i.e. the sum of deviations is minimal)?

I dont mind solve the problem w/ external programs so long as they're "programmable" in some way like R - any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You just have to compute the inverse of your matrix (function solve) and then multiply it with the vector.

Comment: Is this homework?  It's a simple linear algebra operation...

Comment: usually I would say `solve(A,Ax)` but you have 1 degree of freedom here in your question so should be an infinite number of solutions. If you need one specific solution no matter what you can do a generalized penrose inverse: `require(MASS); Ax=matrix(c(1,-3),nrow=2); A=matrix(c(1,0,-1,-3,2,1),nrow=2); sol1=ginv(A)%*%Ax; print(A%*%sol1)`

Comment: @droopy he has a non-square matrix, so the `solve` function won't work

Comment: -1 for not using R syntax.

Comment: Your question example is equivalent to a system of linear eqns. If x is the vector [x,y,z] then your example question is to find x,y,z such that 1x - 2y + 2z = 1 and 0x - 3y + 1z = -3. There will be many such triplets; 3 unknowns but only 2 equations. That's why these questions typically use square matrices, otherwise you will get either more unknowns than equations (as in your case) or more equations than unknowns.